# Создание окна прикрепленного к  координатам дива

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Необходимо создать вспылвающие окно, которое при ресайзе странице всегда оставалось на месте относительно определенного  дива.

окно есть,определяю его местоположенеи при создании

```
var x=$('#div').offset().left+25;
var y=$('#div').offset().top-10;
$('#window').offset({left:x,top:y});
```

пробовал ресайзон контролить, не канает, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Метод offset позволяет только получить значения, но не установить. Пробуйте так:

```
var x=$('#div').offset().left+25;
var y=$('#div').offset().top-10;
$('#window').css({left:x+'px',top:y+'px'});
```

Естественно, position у #window должен быть absolute.

Comment: с сожалению, нет)

Comment: выложите стили #window пожалуйста

Comment: z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:700px;
    padding:15px;
    min-height: 100px;
    height:750px;
    background: white;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;

Comment: Вот, посмотрите. Где у Вас не так?
http://jsfiddle.net/uy2d3/

Comment: парадокс в том что все так.

создаю я его апендом в боди,
   $('body').append('<div id="window" >' +
                                         '<div id="close_b">' +
                                            '<img src="images/service/icon_close.png">' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div id="box_c">' +
                                            '   <div id="box_there"></div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                '</div>');
 буду ковырять искать. если есть идеи , буду благодарен

Comment: Правильнее будет сделать вот так:
var windowElement = $('<div id="window" >' + '<div id="close_b">' + '<img src="images/service/icon_close.png">' + '</div>' + '<div id="box_c">' + ' <div id="box_there"></div>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
$('body').append(windowElement);

И дальше по коду вместо $('#window') использовать windowElement/

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно хотели сделать. Вам нужно определять координаты #idv не только при загрузке страницы, но и при ресайзе. Вот, кажется, то, что Вы хотели:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divBlock = $('#div'),
    windowBlock = $('#window');

  function updatePopupPosition() {
    var offset = divBlock.offset();
    windowBlock.offset({
      top: offset.top - 10,
      left: offset.left + 25
    });
  }

  updatePopupPosition();

  $(window).resize(updatePopupPosition);
});
```

Вот живой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/cxdx9x7b/1/